# Compute the stochastic differential for $t\cdot B_t$ using Ito's Lemma

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider $Y_t=B_t^3$, $t \geq 0$ where $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is standard Brownian Motion.

Here, $dB_t = 0+1\cdot dB_t$ and $G(x,t)=x^3$, What is $dY_t$?

Using Ito's Lemma, we can calculate the partial derivatives and get:

$$\begin{align*}
dY_t &= [3B_t^3\cdot 0+0\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot 6B_t\cdot 1^2]dt + 3B_t^2\cdot 1\cdot dB_t \\
&= 3B_t^2dt + 3B_t^2dB_t
\end{align*}$$

If $Y_t = t\cdot B_t$, how can I use this same logic to get $d(tB_t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Itô's lemma with $g(x,t) = xt$. Notice that $g_x(x,t) = t, g_t(x,t) = x, g_{xx}(x,t) = 0$, so that
\begin{align*}
dY_t &= dg(B_t, t) \\
&=  g_t(B_t, t) dt + g_x(B_t, t) + \frac{1}{2}g_{xx}(B_t,t)(dB_t)^2 \\
&=  B_t dt +t dB_t
\end{align*}

Comment: There is no need to use Ito here. It's a simple product rule.

Comment: @Tobsn Sure, although you may wish to note two things: (i) the OP asked to exhibit Itô's lemma in this question, and (ii) the product rule is a direct consequence of Itô's lemma, so even if I use the product rule, Itô's lemma is carrying most of the weight behind the scenes.

Comment: Regarding (i) sure, I've seen that. But not every question is a good question. (ii) I find the product rule far more elemental then Ito's lemma and I don't like thinking of it as a corollary thereof. To some extend that is like proving the convential product rule in calculus using the chain rule. Sure, it works, but I don't find it instructive.